# %22 instead of quotes - chrome + firefox different behaviour

Tags: php, json, google-chrome, firefox

I have the following function:

```
public function insertProfile() {

    $values = $_POST;

    // unsanitized, don't do this ever. But since everything has to be done quickly... you know
    $name = $values['name'];
    $creditornr = $values['creditornr'];
    $struct = $values['struct'];

    $serialized = json_encode($struct);
    $cleaned = str_replace('""', '"', stripslashes($serialized));

    var_dump($cleaned);
    die();
}
```

Yes, I know, never trust user-input.. But that is another story.

var_dumping `$cleaned` prints in firefox this:

> string(51) "{"0":"sku","1":"abc","2":"def","3":"-","4":"foo","5":"bar"}"

This is exactly the format, I want it to have. However, when I use my script in Chrome, it produces this output:

> string(87) "{"%220%22":"sku","%221%22":"abc","%222%22":"def","%223%22":"-","%224%22":"foo","%225%22":"bar"}"

I figured out, that `%22` is the ASCII-Code for double-quotes (`"`). However, since the output is written to a DB later in that script, it writes the wrong JSON-structure, if used in chrome.

Why is that and how can I get rid of it? I don't want to use `str_replace()` if the user is using chrome, unless there is no other option. Can someone explain why this happens in first place? Is it due the rendering-engine of the browsers?

Comment: Is the code above just a PHP Code snippet or the whole thing that gets executed?

Comment: well, there is HTML and JS involved as well, but I can reproduce the odd behaviour with exactly that code. That is a snippet though.

Comment: Both firefox and chrome have developer tools, which you can use to inspect the HTTP Content-Type header. Is it text/html or text/plain?

Comment: content-type is: text/html

Comment: I tried your code and get the expected output in both browsers. The next suspission I have is javascript. Could you deactivate javascript alltogether? Additionally, when you inspect the source code of the html page in the browser, do you still see the difference?

Comment: I can't disable JS, since 99% of the app is running on JS. But for the other thing: yes, in the browser, in the source-code + firebug.

Comment: OK, to isolate the PHP Code from the javascript code, I would suggest you prepare a super simple and pure PHP Page, which runs that script without any javascript at all. If the two browsers still show a difference, I have no explanation. Otherwise, you know the problem is related to javascript and debug there.